# In algorithm2e, how to force non-italic font in the condition block of While

Tags: algorithm2e

I have this snippet:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \While{$|\text{OPEN}| > 0$}{
      $u = \textsc{ExtractMinimum}(\text{OPEN})$ \\
    }
    \caption{\textsc{$A*$}$(s, t, w, h)$}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot find a way to make LaTeX typeset on the first line "OPEN" instead of "*OPEN*"? Any advice?

Comment: I'm confused.  The picture you have shows OPEN, not _OPEN_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `algorithm2e` environment sets the first argument to `\While` using `ArgSty`, which is, by default, `\emph`. When you use `\text` in math mode, the font which was current when the formula started is used, italics, in this case.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetArgSty{textnormal}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \While{$|\text{OPEN}| > 0$}{
      $u = \textsc{ExtractMinimum}(\text{OPEN})$ \\
    }
    \caption{\textsc{$A*$}$(s, t, w, h)$}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The style that by default is rendered in italics is `FuncArgSty`.

Comment: (1) It's not **`\SetProgSty`** but rather **`\SetProcSty`**. (2) **`\SetProcSty`** does not do what I want it to do. (3) There is no **`ArgSty`**, but rather **`\SetArgSty`**.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I'm sure it was working. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: I don't understand how, but it worked. `algorithm2e` is a weird package.